# Do weapon precision upgrades improve your squad mates?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have been dubious as to how much weapon upgrades that affect precision really works for your squad mates. For the player it's fairly simple - it's easier to hit because the weapon reticle is smaller or the bullet spread is tighter.

But how does it work for my squade mates like Ashley or James? Do they simply hit more often or are precision upgrades wasted on anyone but the player?

Comment: The `Mass-Effect` tag refers to the first game in the series, so I've removed it from the question.

Comment: Why? I put it there intentionally, since precision mods can be used in ME1 as well. And my question extends to both ME1 and ME3.

Comment: The combat system of the two games are not inherently comparable. Since you mentioned James, a `mass-effect-3` specific character, I had assumed you were most interested in mass effect 3. If you are curious about the same thing in `Mass Effect`, I suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: Precision mods in  ME1 were explicitly per-weapon, and they were one of the many reasons why inventory management in that game was a bit of a pain. ME2 and ME3 worked significantly differently.

Comment: WRT your question, given the way they're described -- and the fact that all weapons are now fabricated onboard the Normandy once you acquire the design -- I'd say that weapon upgrades affect the *weapons* regardless of who among your squad wields them.

Comment: (I'm at work so I can't access any of the sites that might be able to answer conclusively -- masseffect.wikia.com might know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more precision a squad mate has, the less spreading for the shots he fires. It works in the same way that different weapons do.

If you equip your squad mate with two different sniper rifles with a significant different on the precision you can see how the shots of one of the weapon miss more often, specially on the far shots.

You can imagine it as a circle. The more precision, the smaller the circle goes, and all the shots are set in a random place on the circle when aiming for an objetive.

So yes, the weapon upgrades will work for your teammates.